# Filling in a number field in Cucumber/Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

I'm running a rails app on 3.1's beta, and have a field of type="number", to use the new number selector in HTML5. It works great. BUT.

When I run a cucumber step to fill it in in my tests, it fails, because it isn't a text field. The 'fill_in' step in Capybara doesn't seem to work with number fields. How can I fill in a number field on my capybara/cucumber test?

Comment: what version of capybara are you using? And which driver?

Comment: 1.0.0 - is there a version that will fix this?

Comment: And, using selenium for the driver, though if I just run it with nothing specified, it does the same.

Comment: Not sure, but I've certainly been able to fill in number fields without issue, so was wondering if you were using an old version.

Comment: Nope. And the source code for fillable_field doesn't list number as one of the types it supports? Are you just using the 'fill_in' command to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Two years later, a different problem: selenium-webdriver 2.41 does not fill in number fields.  Fixed in 2.42.

- [Selenium Issue 7291:     Input field with type=number cannot be set in Firefox 29](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7291&can=1&q=number&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)
- [Capybara does not fill input type="number" #1304](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1304)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had just capitalized part of the field name that I shouldn't have. Error message is just misleading.

Comment: Good stuff. We actually ditched the number field - too many issues with the validation seeming to change with each Chrome release.